# Lewis structures overlapping with parentheses in main text

Tags: spacing, chemfig

I have to put lewis structures in parentheses in the main text as shown in MWE. However, the lewis structure and parenthesis is overlapping as shown in the figure.

[image]

How can the parenthesis be automatically spaced such that they don't overlap with the lewis structure?

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\noindent
Radical 1 (\lewis{0.,Q}) \\
Radical 2 (\lewis{1.,R}) \\
Radical 3 (\lewis{2.,S}) \\
Radical 4 (\lewis{3.,T}) \\
Radical 5 (\lewis{4.,U}) \\
Radical 6 (\lewis{5.,V}) \\
Radical 7 (\lewis{6.,W}) \\
Radical 8 (\lewis{7.,X}) \\
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `\Lewis{}` instead. It takes account of the dots in the bounding boxes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
    \noindent
    Radical 1 (\Lewis{0.,Q}) \\
    Radical 2 (\Lewis{1.,R}) \\
    Radical 3 (\Lewis{2.,S}) \\
    Radical 4 (\Lewis{3.,T}) \\
    Radical 5 (\Lewis{4.,U}) \\
    Radical 6 (\Lewis{5.,V}) \\
    Radical 7 (\Lewis{6.,W}) \\
    Radical 8 (\Lewis{7.,X}) \\
\end{document}
```

[image: lewis]